# Any way to make this question on processing tracking data on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I used the chat to ask a question which is IMO clearly off-topic here, but looking at the chat history I realized that there is very little traffic, so I'm going to ask suggestions to make it on-topic here (of course, it may just not be  possible to make it on-topic: if so, I'll just not post the question).

I like hiking quite a lot, and I've recorded a fair amount of track records with an app on Android (**I can provide the app name if needed**). I would like to compute summary statistics for my tracks (e.g., average length of a track, min, max, $q_{10}$, $q_{90}$, etc.). Is there a simple, preferably free way to do that?  I can export the tracks in various formats (CSV, GPX, KML, KMZ, etc.), so I could use R to postprocess them, but I don't know the format (for example, I don't know what units the app uses for speed, when using the CSV format), so I was wondering if there were pre-made solutions, or if I should just bite the bullet, study the format and write my own R script.

Comment: @Tim I guess you're right. I was hoping there was a ready-made solution, but even if there was one, CV wouldn't be the right place where to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a programming/software issue, so it would be off-topic. You need to (1) check the documentation/"hack" the app to obtain your data and then (2) transform it into R-readable format. For (1) you would need to ask someone who knows the app (stackoverflow, or user forums) and (2) is just a question about finding appropriate software to transform between data-types.